# Executing script on woocommerce_after_checkout_validation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to execute a script on said hook to create a loading graphic after the form has been validated, when hooking this script to the hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'create_loading_gui');
function create_loading_gui($data)
{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#main > .container").css("opacity", 0);
        $("#main").addClass("loading-overlay");
        $(".woocommerce").css("display", "none");
        });
        </script>';

}
```

The resulting code just outputs the scripts into the browser's console with "malformed json fixed", I suppose it's with the checkout.js.

If it's not with this way, how do I manipulate the DOM on the checkout page after the form as been validated?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late for an answer but I wanna answer it if anyone else needs help.

Problem is that you cannot echo anything after documents has been rendered. Solution in your case would be to use AJAX.